Excel: refer to column by number
I'd like to write an Excel function that uses SUMIF on a column, and refer to the column by its number instead of its letter. I know about R1C1 references, but I do not want to switch the whole workbook to that type of reference. Is there any way to use something like a R1C1 reference just in one instance in the workbook?

You can use R1C1 style with INDIRECT. e.g =SUMIF(INDIRECT("R1C1:R5C1",FALSE),">0") sums range A1:A5 with criteria ">0"

Instead of any volatile functions can use INDEX() --> =SUMIF(INDEX(A:C,,1),">0") or as in shown with the example data in answers: =SUMIF(INDEX(A1:C3,,1),"a",INDEX(A1:C3,,3))

Perhaps instead of using any volatile functions like OFFSET( ) & INDIRECT( ) can use INDEX() Function.


=SUMIF(INDEX(A1:C3,,1),"a",INDEX(A1:C3,,3))


A Friendly Suggestion

OFFSET( ) is a flexible function and it can point to a
different-sized range that is calculated on-the-fly. But it is a
volatile function. If you go to a completely unrelated cell and enter a number, all of the OFFSET( ) functions will
calculate—even if that cell has nothing to do with.
It has been found, Excel is very careful to spend time calculating the
cells that needs to be calculated. But once you use the
OFFSET( ), all of the OFFSET( ) cells, plus
everything downline from the OFFSET(), starts calculating
after every change in the worksheet.
Why it matters ? INDEX( ) is not volatile. You enjoy all of the flexible goodness of OFFSET( ) without the
time-sucking recalculations over and over.


Example Data used as shown by Ike Madam.


You can use OFFSET
=SUMIF(OFFSET(D1:D3,,-3),"a",OFFSET(D1:D3,,-1))


